# Instantiate variable exception in Processing

Tags: java, constructor, processing

I am trying to create a constructor for a class

```
// Variables to send to Host
private class ParameterClass {
  public String parameter;
  public int value;
  public Boolean sended;
}

public class SendToHostClass {
  private int sizeBuffer;
  public ParameterClass[] parameterList;

  SendToHostClass(int sizeBufferConf) {
    sizeBuffer = sizeBufferConf;
    parameterList = new ParameterClass[sizeBuffer];
  }

  public void Put (String parameter, int valuePut, Boolean sendedPut) {
    for (int index=0; index<sizeBuffer; index++) {
      if (parameter == parameterList[index].parameter) {
        parameterList[index].value = valuePut;
        parameterList[index].sended = sendedPut;
        exit();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

so I declare the varible

```
SendToHostClass sendToHost;
```

and instantiate `sendToHost` in `setup()` Processing method using

```
sendToHost = new SendToHostClass(10);
sendToHost.parameterList[0].value = 0;
```

As I run the code, it returns me the error message

> Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at sketch_gui.setup(sketch_gui.java:273)    at
>   processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2117)     at
>   processing.opengl.PGL$PGLListener.display(PGL.java:2472)  at
>   jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:548)
>     at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:533)
>     at
>   jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawableBase$2.run(GLAutoDrawableBase.java:280)
>     at
>   jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:904)
>     at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:822)
>     at com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow.display(GLWindow.java:543)   at
>   processing.opengl.PGL.requestDraw(PGL.java:814)   at
>   processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.requestDraw(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:1566)
>     at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2020)   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

So what am I doing wrong?

I also discovered that if I instantiate each list object separately, it gives no error:

```
sendToHost = new SendToHostClass(10);
sendToHost.parameterList[0] = new ParameterClass();
sendToHost.parameterList[0].value = 0;
```

but it seems wrong, due to it looks that `parameterList` members are being instantiated twice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you creating an instance of a private class from another class?

Comment: On a side note, if you're writing this as real Processing code, rather than as Java that just uses the Processing library, visibility rules aren't part of the Processing programming model. Processing sketches don't use public/private/protected annotation. It'll work, but they're not strictly speaking part of the programming model (Processing sketches aren't packaged in '1 file per class' like Java code is, it's compiled as a flat single-classed file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
parameterList = new ParameterClass[sizeBuffer];
```

The above statement is only creating an array, but not initializing the array elements. The array elements are initialized by their default value, which is `null`, in case you have the array of some `custom type` or some reference. So, you need to initialize the array elements separately using for loop.

So, in your constructor you need to add a loop:

```
SendToHostClass(int sizeBufferConf) {
    sizeBuffer = sizeBufferConf;
    parameterList = new ParameterClass[sizeBuffer];

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeBuffer; i++) {
        parameterList[i] = new ParameterList();
    }
  }
```

But of course, first you need to make your class `public`, and prefer to make your fields `private` instead of `public`, and provide public accessors to make them accessible from outside.

Answer (score 0):

> but it seems wrong, due to it looks that parameterList members are being instantiated twice.

You need to understand the difference between creating an array and populating it with references to objects. This:

```
parameterList = new ParameterClass[sizeBuffer];
```

... *just* creates an array which initially is full of null references. If you want to make the elements *non-null*, you have to do so explicitly... which is what you're doing in this line:

```
sendToHost.parameterList[0] = new ParameterClass();
```

You might well be better not using an array to start with though - why do you *want* an array? It's likely that you'd be better offer with a `List<ParameterClass>`.

(As an aside, you should learn about and follow the Java naming conventions, and also keep fields private.)